# Assign a unique id to 3 tables which have the same column name in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to give unique id to 3 tables which have the same column name in mysql.
when inserting a new value the value should be compared with all three table column values and assign a new unique id to the inserted table. Is this possible in mysql.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a temporary table that has all the values aggregated together so you can check.

What do you mean by "unique id"? A suitable hash function like `SHA1()` usually gives you something reasonably unique.

Comment: Unique mean the value should be a global value to all three tables. i did what you say earlier. but if i want to update those tables how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: Just re-create the table using whatever method you employed the first time.